# Unable to resolve deprecation notice with composer

Tags: laravel, composer-php, ubuntu-16.04

I have asked my hosting provider to switch the operating system on my server from Centos to Ubuntu. Upon downloading all my files from GitHub and running "composer install" I am getting the following error in terminal:

> Deprecation Notice: The behavior of unparenthesized expressions containing both '.' and '+'/'-' will change in PHP 8: '+'/'-' will take a higher precedence in /usr/share/php/Composer/Downloader/GitDownloader.php:223
>   Deprecation Notice: The behavior of unparenthesized expressions containing both '.' and '+'/'-' will change in PHP 8: '+'/'-' will take a higher precedence in /usr/share/php/Composer/Downloader/SvnDownloader.php:132

After this composer quits so I need to be able to resolve this not worked around it.

Already tried solutions:

- Uninstall and re-install composer.
- Upgrade, update, and install commands attempted.
- A fresh install of Laravel in case of corruption on Git clone.

Comment: Update your `composer` and try again.

Comment: composer update and composer install both throw the same Dep Notice with the error   [ErrorException]
  "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?


also tried uninstalling and re-installing

Comment: `composer self-update`

Comment: @The Alpha  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Command "self-update" is not defined.

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#self-update-selfupdate-

Comment: Which version of Composer are you using? As you can see at https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/1291a16ce3f48bfdeca39d64fca4875098af4d7b/src/Composer/Downloader/SvnDownloader.php#L132, the current stable version (v1.9.3) does not contain code at line 132 that contains stuff given in that message

Comment: ```curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer``` worked for me

Answer (score 6):

upgrade composer using this command `composer self-update`
happy coding

Answer (score 2):

While working on a new project this morning, I encountered a similar error. And my solution : if an expression has . with +,- etc.  **you must add parenthesis**,

```
   $this->io->writeError('    <info>' .count($changes) - 10 . ' more files modified, choose "v" to view the full list</info>');
```

to

```
   $this->io->writeError('    <info>'.(count($changes) - 10) . ' more files modified, choose "v" to view the full list</info>');
```

Answer (score 1):

echo 'Total' . 5 + 5;

Deprecated: The behavior of unparenthesized expressions containing both '.' and '+'/'-' will change in PHP 8: '+'/'-' will take a higher precedence in ... on line ...

From PHP 8 and later, this will be evaluated as 'total' + (5 + 5), with the + and - operators taking higher precedence.

Comment: use (5 + 5) insted of  5 + 5

Answer (score 0):

You can rename the composer.phar file with composerOld.phar and download new file manually from the official site and put it over there. 
It will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update composer using the following code.

```
composer self-update
```

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Once you [earn](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146472/what-is-the-best-way-to-increase-my-reputation-and-privileges) enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will gain privileges to [upvote answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points.

Answer (score -1):

If `composer self-update` is not solve your problem, re-installing composer is best way.

https://getcomposer.org/download/

My composer also gave these errors and self-update not worked.

Answer (score -2):

**How to solve it**

Put parenthesis surrounding

```
$someString . ($a + $b) . $anotherString
```

**What is the error**

If you'd write something like this:

```
echo "sum: " . $a + $b;
```

PHP would previously interpret it like this:

```
echo ("sum: " . $a) + $b;
```

PHP 8 will make it so that it's interpreted like this:

```
echo "sum: " . ($a + $b);
```

source: https://stitcher.io/blog/new-in-php-74

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer: what should the OP do to resolve the error message?